# CSS Grid: controlled auto-fit

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

Is there a way to control the number of items `repeat(auto-fit, _)` creates?

I want everything to align to 12-col grid (see the screehshot below) and exclude numbers that 12 is not divisible by, like 5, 7, 8, etc.

Here is my React code just for the record:

```
<Grid gap="2rem" gridTemplateColumns="repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr))">
  <Block bgColor="blue" height="2rem" width="100%"/>
  ...
</Grid>
```

which results in the CSS below:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
```

So is there a way to tell `repeat(auto-fit, _`) or the grid itself to put only 1, 2, 3, 4 and 6 items in a row?

I would like to avoid media-queries cause they are global and not all containers are screen-wide so even such hack won't be a universal solution. Upcoming "container-queries" aren't supported in most browsers yet.

[image]